# error with hyperref and the krantz class

Tags: hyperref, pdftex

I'm using the [krantz.cls](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=0uWnuKnx) to write a book, and I ran into an error with the `hyperref` package. Here is a minimal example (`test.tex`):

```
\documentclass{krantz}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}
\end{document}
```

When I compile it with `pdflatex test.tex`, I get this error:

```
Runaway argument?
{Introduction}]{[}{Introduction}]{Introduction} \end {document} 
! File ended while scanning use of \Hy@org@chapter.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
<*> test.tex
```

Without `hyperref`, it compiles fine. I appreciate if anyone can tell me why this happens and how to fix it.

```
$ pdflatex --version
pdfTeX 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (TeX Live 2012/Debian)
kpathsea version 6.1.0
Copyright 2012 Peter Breitenlohner (eTeX)/Han The Thanh (pdfTeX).
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the pdfTeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the pdfTeX source.
Primary author of pdfTeX: Peter Breitenlohner (eTeX)/Han The Thanh (pdfTeX).
Compiled with libpng 1.2.49; using libpng 1.2.49
Compiled with zlib 1.2.7; using zlib 1.2.7
Compiled with poppler version 0.20.4

$ head `kpsewhich hyperref.sty` -n 34 | tail -n 4
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1995/12/01]
\ProvidesPackage{hyperref}
  [2012/05/13 v6.82q %
  Hypertext links for LaTeX]
```

---

### Update

I contacted the author of this LaTeX class and the problem was solved. See the corrected [krantz.cls](https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown/blob/master/inst/examples/krantz.cls).

Comment: Seems to be an error in the class; contact the author.

Comment: Despite the class' claim - this is not a standard LaTeX class.  In particular its internal command `\@chapter` used for chapters has a non-standard argument format, which `hyperref` therefore does not recognise.

Comment: @AndrewSwann Thanks a lot! That `\@chapter` is exactly what I want to know; at least I know the direction to fix it now.